# Compare and if not entry update table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables in my stored procedure, one is an actual table and one is temp table. What I am doing is getting data into my temp table. I have all data in the temp table, now I want to compare if same data is in my actual table; if not insert into main table from temp table.

```
create table #X
(
    Field_PL  varchar(50),
    Field_Station varchar(50),
    Field_Value varchar(50),
    Field_EFox_PL varchar(50),
    lasteditdt datetime,
    disable bit 
)
```

Please find the table structure. Attached is the temp table #X and have the same structure of main table say X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `#X` might have duplicates, and you do not want to insert those duplicates... using [**`except`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql):

```
insert into MainTable (Field_PL, Field_Station, Field_Value, Field_EFox_PL, lasteditdt, disable)
select Field_PL, Field_Station, Field_Value, Field_EFox_PL, lasteditdt, disable
from #X
except 
select Field_PL, Field_Station, Field_Value, Field_EFox_PL, lasteditdt, disable
from MainTable
```

If `#X` might have duplicates, and you want to insert those duplicates... using `not exists()`:

```
insert into MainTable (Field_PL, Field_Station, Field_Value, Field_EFox_PL, lasteditdt, disable)
select 
    Field_PL
  , Field_Station
  , Field_Value
  , Field_EFox_PL
  , lasteditdt
  , disable
from #X as x
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from MainTable i
  where i.Field_PL      = xField_PL
        i.Field_Station = xField_Station
        i.Field_Value   = xField_Value
        i.Field_EFox_PL = xField_EFox_PL
        i.lasteditdt    = xlasteditdt
        i.disable       = xdisable
  )
```